# assign a folder path, part of which changes between environments, to a variable

Tags: perl, dynamic, path, directory

I need help with assigning a dynamic folder path to a variable. The last part of the path has the name of the environment (like dev, test or prod environments).

```
my $logdir=/home/ssr/GC/dpg_CR_CTM
```

here dpg is the environment name. If i have to run this script in a different environment, the folder starts with that environment name.

Is there a way i can make it more generalised, like below?

```
my $logdir=/home/ssr/GC/*_CR_CTM
```

Comment: Does the script know in which environment it's running?

Comment: It isn't at all clear what you want to do. Please can you explain better? Do your “environments” correspond to different computer systems? Will there only ever be one directory that matches `/home/ssr/GC/*_CR_CTM`?

Comment: yes, it knows which environment it is running

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If the `*` wildcard works reliably (e.g. you don't have multiple locations that would match) then you can use `glob`.

```
my $logdir = glob ( "/home/ssr/GC/*_CR_CTM" );
```

but bear in mind if there are multiple that match, that'll only return the first in the list.

Otherwise, you'll need to detect your environment somehow - and then use that to decide. (glob may help here too).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but when i try this and print i am getting empty string into logdir. I have included
use File::Glob; 
Is there something else to be done apart from the above?
thank you.

Comment: You don't need File::Glob. `glob` is a perl builtin

Comment: And if you `echo /home/ssr/GC/*_CR_CTM` from a shell, what does it give you? Because glob should expand that path, and return the first 'match' in a scalar context. (So you can either use a `while` or `for` loop with scalar/list context respectively)